# String variables loose their values when delivered to another object

Tags: java, class, variables

I'm trying to build a simple program to get xml-files into objects and vice versa for school project. I'm trying to store the xml-data i get from between the tags into a object and then store that object to another object of another class. The problem is, that every time i try to pass on some Strings from the xml-parses to the first storage object (such as names, platforms etc.) they loose their values. The string does get delivered to the storage object, but the storage just goes from being a "XXXXXX" to "". Neither our theacer or I was able to solve this. Any ideas?

Here are the classes causing the havoc.

```
public class MySaxParser
extends DefaultHandler {
  public static int element;
  public static String elementit[] = {"name","studio","genre","platform","published"};
  public static String Name, Studio, Genre, Platform, Published;
  public static OutFile outF = new OutFile();
  private static Library Pelit = new Library();
  private static Game peli;


   public Library getLib(){
       return Pelit;
   }

  public void parse() {

    /*if (args.length != 1) {
      System.out.println("Usage: java .MySaxParser [URI]");
      System.exit(0);
    }*/
     // oli public static ja metodin ulkopuolella
    System.setProperty("javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory",
                       "org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl");

    //String uri = args[0];

    String uri = "src\\gamelib\\Gamelibrary.xml";
    try {

      if (outF.askName())
          outF.openFile(); // ok, avataan tiedosto
      SAXParserFactory parserFactory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
      parserFactory.setValidating(true);
      parserFactory.setNamespaceAware(false);
      parserFactory.setFeature(
          "http://apache.org/xml/features/validation/schema", true);
      MySaxParser MySaxParserInstance = new MySaxParser();
      SAXParser parser = parserFactory.newSAXParser();
      parser.parse(uri, MySaxParserInstance);
    }
    catch (IOException exception) {
      exception.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (SAXException exception) {
      exception.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (ParserConfigurationException exception) {
      exception.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (FactoryConfigurationError exception) {
      exception.printStackTrace();
    }
      System.out.println("Prasing done.");
  }


  public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length) throws SAXException {

    String s = new String(ch, start, length); 
    s = s.trim();
     switch(element){         
          case 1:
              peli.setName(s);
              break;       
          case 2:
              peli.setStudio(s);
              break;
          case 3:
              peli.setGenre(s);
              break;
          case 4:
              peli.setPlaform(s);
              break;
          case 5:
              peli.setPublished(s);
              break;
    //outF.write(s); jos halutaan printata tiedostoon nin tämä käyttöön

    }
  }
  public void endDocument() throws SAXException {


  }


  public void endElement(String url, String localName, String qName) throws
      SAXException {
      System.out.println("Loppuva elementti: "+qName);
    if (qName.equals("game"))
        Pelit.AddGame(peli);

  }


  public void startDocument() throws SAXException {

  }


  public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
                           Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
      System.out.println("Alkava elementti: "+qName);
      switch(qName){         
          case "name":
             element = 1;
              break;       
          case "studio":
              element = 2;
              break;
          case "genre":
              element = 3;
              break;
          case "platform":
              element = 4;
              break;
          case "published":
              element = 5;
              break;
          case "game":
              peli = new Game();
              break;
      }
  }


  public void fatalError(SAXParseException e) throws SAXException {
    throw new java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException(
        "Method fatalError() not yet implemented.");
  }
```

And the storage class.

```
public class Game {
    private static  String Name, Studio, Genre, Plaform, Published;


    public String getName() {return Name;}
    public String getStudio() {return Studio;}
    public String getGenre() {return Genre;}
    public String getPlaform() {return Plaform;}
    public String getPublished() {return Published;}



    public void setName(String Name) {this.Name = Name;}
    public void setStudio(String Studio) {this.Studio = Studio;}
    public void setGenre(String Genre) {this.Genre = Genre;}
    public void setPlaform(String Plaform) {this.Plaform = Plaform;}
    public void setPublished(String Published) {this.Published = Published;}     
}
```

I've debugged the code numerous times, tried unspeakable things with it, and now i'm clueless.

Once to clarify. Debugging shows that `peli.setName(s)` does carry out the right value - lets say "Derp" - and it does get registered to `Game.Name`, but the value goes from "Derp" to "" if i go just one step further in my debugging.

Comment: _tried unspeakable things with it_ What did you do to your computer?!

Comment: Can you include a copy of your xml input file?

Comment: [The xml file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2w4wn2chcpyliqy/lib.xml)

There's a link to the .xml file :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Important: add @Override before overriden methods like `startElement`. If you had an error in the signature, a compiler error would say: does not override any method. Now with a wrong parameter type, the DefaultHandler's startElement would be called.

Furthermore `characters` might be called more than once:
hold a String variable

```
private StringBuilder elementValue;
```

In startElement do:

```
elementValue = new StringBuilder()
```

and in characters, without trimming:

```
elementValue.append(s);
```

and in endElement save it, with what now is in characters

```
peli.setName(elementValue.toString());
```

This works as you have leaf element without inner tags.

Comment: Thanks a lot!
These answers solved the problem!
I wasn't confident what to use as a buffer in this case, but using `StringBuilder`really solved the whole thing =)

Answer (score 1):

I am not totally clear about your question, but here is what I think is the problem:

Your `characters` method is being called multiple times by the parser, with some of them containing just whitespace characters or no characters.

To illistrate:

```
<foo>
   <bar>The Text I Want</bar>
</foo>
```

In the above XML, the parser is free to call `characters` in between `</bar>` and `</foo>` and it will contain some whitespace (tabs and new lines if your XML is formatted).

You should validate that you are in the correct element before storing the information retrieved from `characters`. I usually do this by keeping a stack that represents where I am in the xml hierarchy.

Also, all of the characters inside of an element may not be returned by a single call of `characters`. XML parsers are allowed to split the characters of an element into multiple `characters` events. This means that you need to use the `startElement` and `endElement` events to create/flush a buffer that you write to with the `characters` method.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what's happening... The method `characters` does not necessarily get called only once for an element's content. Character data may be broken up by nodes such as comments, CDATA sections, processing instructions and more. Even if that is not the case and the content of an element is one block of text, the XML parser may decide to read it in chunks, break it up at newlines or even give you empty strings at some point.

What you need to do instead is keep a StringBuilder or similar buffer, append the indicated piece of char[] when the `characters` method is called and only use its complete value once method `endElement` is called. After that, you can empty the builder and start using it again for the next element.

I have some additional advice for you. There is no need to make the fields in class `Game` static. To me, those look like they should really be instance fields. I don't know if this is an assignment or excercise to learn how to write SAX handlers, but if it is not and this is part of a larger project, I strongly suggest you look into using JAXB instead, which is ideal for going from XML to Java objects and vice-versa.

Comment: It's just an exercise :)
Still took a look at JAXB though. Didn't really understand all of the documentation (being a newbie with coding) but still gonna give it a go with the same assignment.
Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Just adding that I built the whole thing from ground up with JAXB, and with a bit of experimenting, JAXB seems like a reasonably easy and efficient way to get on with marshalling and unmarshalling ;)

Comment: Excellent! Technologies like this let you avoid reinventing the wheel. While it does have some tricky details in advanced usage, JAXB is a great tech to have in your toolbox.